Why sequence_out is xx in the 2-bit up-counter testbench?
I'm trying to write a 2-bit up-counter in Verilog, and it must have dff in it's design.  But, when I test it, outputs are = xx.  Can you please help me to fix it?
module dff(d,clk,q);
    input d,clk;
    output reg q;
    
    always @(posedge clk ) begin
       q <=d;
    end
   
endmodule 
module sequence_counter (
    input clk,
    output reg [1:0]sequence
);
    wire [1:0]a;
    dff d0(.d(~a[0]) , .clk(clk) , .q(a[0]));
    dff d1(.d(a[1]^ a[0]) , .clk(clk) , .q(a[1]));
always @(posedge clk) begin
    sequence = a;
end
    
endmodule

and this is the testbench :
 `timescale 1ns / 1ns

module tb;

    reg clk;
    wire reg [1:0] out_sequence;
    sequence_counter uut_sequence(.clk(clk) , .sequence(out_sequence));
    initial begin
    clk = 0;
    $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);
       
            #10 $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);
             #10 $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);
              #10 $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);
               #10 $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);
                #10 $display("Initial state at time=%0t, sequence_out =%b", $time, out_sequence);

        $finish;
    end
    
    // Clock generation for sequence_counter
    always #5 clk = ~clk;
endmodule 

the output I get is this:
Initial state at time=0, sequence_out =xx
Initial state at time=10, sequence_out =xx
Initial state at time=20, sequence_out =xx
Initial state at time=30, sequence_out =xx
Initial state at time=40, sequence_out =xx
Initial state at time=50, sequence_out =xx


The quickest fix is to initialize q in the dff module:
output reg q=0;

This eliminates the unknown (x) values:
Initial state at time=10, sequence_out =00
Initial state at time=20, sequence_out =01
Initial state at time=30, sequence_out =10
Initial state at time=40, sequence_out =11
Initial state at time=50, sequence_out =00

It would be better to model a counter using standard behavioral code, instead of instantiating flip-flops.  Alternately, you should use a reset input signal to reset all the logic.
